# How to interpolate types and object references in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interpolation

In Typescript I have the following:

```
function determineInterface(interface: string) {
  let newInterface: string;
  // Logic (For example will make newInterface = MyCustomType through a switch statement or something)
  return newInterface;
}

const payload = context.Requestbody as determineInterface(); // Don't worry about the context.Requestbody, it's just an obj with data

// The result should be something like 
const payload = context.Requestbody as MyCustomInterface;
```

But I can't figure out why I can't dynamically create this interface programmatically with determineInterface()

*** Also for the object reference I have something as such in Typescript: ***

```
export const createSomething = (subMethodName: any /* METHOD */, e: any) : string | undefined => {
    return this.SomeMethod.subMethodName; // I want subMethodName to equal nestedSubMethod() and call that method nested in the SomeMethod class 
}

class SomeMethod {
    nestedSubMethod() {
     // LOGIC
     return 'EMPTY STRING FOR TEST';
    }
}

// Call the function and pass in the method's name
createSomething("nestedSubMethod")
```

Comment: This is impossible as stated. The type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TS is compiled to JS. There is no *type reflection* in TS: you can't treat a type as a value.  Additionally, TS does not have *dependent types* in general, so you can't treat a value as a type either. There are approaches which might give you similar results, but in the end it will end up looking like just using `class` constructors as your values and their instance types as types. I don't know that this is a [mcve] I can use to suggest anything, though.

Comment: Even if you could write `context.Requestbody as determineInterface()` (which you can't), isn't `determineInterface()` supposed to take a `string` input?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really treat an interface keyword as a value in TypeScript.

Interfaces are useful because we can set up a contract between one class and another class and say if you do xyz, imagine all the functionality I am going to give you.

So let's say you are working on a bubble sort algorithm, you could put it inside of a Sorter class like so:

```
export class Sorter {
   sort(): void {
     const {length} = this.collection;

     for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (this.collection.compare(j, j + 1)) {
          this.collection.swap(j, j + 1);
        }
      }
    }
   }
}
```

I am missing something aren't I?

What is the `collection` property? Where did it come from? What type is it? Well, in this case it's an array of numbers, it's the collection of data I want to sort.

But shouldn't I be initializing it and adding a type to it?

Yes, so let's define a `constructor()` like so:

```
export class Sorter {
  constructor(collection: number[]) {}

  sort(): void {
    const { length } = this.collection;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
    if (this.collection.compare(j, j + 1)) {
      this.collection.swap(j, j + 1);
    }
  }
}
}
}

const sorter = new Sorter([10, 3, -5, 0]);
```

Now I can shorten up the above syntax by using a modifier of my constructor argument like so:

```
export class Sorter {
  constructor(public collection: number[]) {}

  sort(): void {
    const { length } = this.collection;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
    if (this.collection.compare(j, j + 1)) {
      this.collection.swap(j, j + 1);
    }
  }
}


 }
}

const sorter = new Sorter([10, 3, -5, 0]);
```

So this sorting algorithm only works with an array of numbers, but what if you wanted to work with a string of characters or a Linked List?

How would you redesign this thing?

We could do something like this:

```
export class Sorter {
  constructor(public collection: number[] | string) {}

  sort(): void {
    const { length } = this.collection;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (this.collection.compare(j, j + 1)) {
          this.collection.swap(j, j + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case I am using the index signature bracket notation for the sorting algorithm and now I am applying it on the union operator of string and array of numbers. This would create a gotcha where I could only read values. TypeScript will not allow me to compile that code.

That's where interfaces come in.

So I defined an interface with all the different properties you must have to be used with the sorter:

```
interface Sortable {
  length: number;
  compare(leftIndex: number, rightIndex: number): boolean;
  swap(leftIndex: number, rightIndex: number): void;
}

export class Sorter {
  constructor(public collection: Sortable) {}

  sort(): void {
    const { length } = this.collection;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (this.collection.compare(j, j + 1)) {
          this.collection.swap(j, j + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```